# Community wiki about bugs in graph related functions?

Tags: discussion

It seems that there's a lot of bugs in graph related functions, and I think it's necessary to have a wiki post that makes clear all the problems inside them. Should we have something like this?

**Related Links**

[None-simple graphs and attributes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124228/how-to-assign-edgeweight-to-a-non-simple-graph) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92014/issues-adding-properties-to-multigraph)

[FindMinimumCostFlow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119088/the-unexpected-behavior-of-findminimumcostflow)

[FindMaximumFlow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118130/findmaximumflow-generates-a-weird-result)

welcome to add things in~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "a lot of bugs in graph related functions"

That's what the tags are for, to make clear the relationship between the issues raised.  You could find the graph-related bugs by going to [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs-and-networks+bugs).

If the issues are identical, then they'll get marked as duplicates, if not then they should have their own Q&A.

I don't personally see a benefit to having a giant, one-size-fits-all, graph-bug uber-post.  When a post gets too large, it isn't digestible to me.  I like for each separate issue to have its own Q&A, and for them to be cross-linked when related.  A lot of people find the "Common Pitfalls" post to be very helpful, but I can't personally read through it, it's just way too large.  If someone links to a particular answer in that post, I find that beneficial, but I'll never just send a newbie to that post and say "Read this".

That being said, you are free to make any answer of yours a community wiki.

Comment: oh, it seems that I didn't make full use of search~ thanks a lot!

Comment: It wasn't fully clear to me how to do a multi-tag filter when I was on the tags page, I actually had to find [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17008/311642) to see how to do it